# Form generation on the fly / Dynamic forms / forms generated from models

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms, symfony1, yii

Has anyone tips with building applications similar too wufoo.com? I am building an app where the logged in user creates forms in a similar manner...what i am wondering is if zend, symfony or yii is best suited for this?

I will be collecting tips here for other to see easier.

advantages of the frameworks that could help with this:

- Symfony has doctrine (but forms are deployed by running a script?)
- Zend has its form and subform
  integrations (and perhaps integrating
  doctrine is possible?)
- Zend has form_decorators but they have a high threshold to learn.
- yii has its form builder and a good PDO database connection

or are there any other frameworks that simplify "form generation on the fly"?

*PS. djangos solution is very interesting but it needs to be in php.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally working with symfony I know that this is possible using symfony. You can generate forms on the fly in this manner. I think that Zend Framework does this in a similar way, so that would be an appropriate choice as well.

How you would do it in symfony, although it is "bending" the framework a bit:

1. Create a table with forms (name, etc.) and a table with formfields (type, name, required)
2. Create a sfForm class with a `configure()` method that pulls the fields for the given form and dynanically adds the form fields to `$this->widgetSchema`, and the validators to `$this->validatorSchame`.
3. Go :)

This is somewhat not what the form framework is meant for (dynamic fields in this way), but I have successfully used it for some projects.

Regarding the Javascript mentioned by Codacula: I don't think there is anything in the question that propts the kind of Javascript usage that is mentioned. It is 
*likely* that some Javascript will go into this, but it is not part of the question in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any that specifically specialize in generating forms on the fly. This seems mostly like a Javascript based venture, so you'll likely end up using a heavy Javascript-based too.

Also, form generation isn't as easy as using a framework, especially for people who won't be using that specific framework. A lot of frameworks add in hidden fields or name the fields a certain way. I'm willing to bet it would end up more of a headache trying to make something for the general population using a pre-made framework than it would coming up with your own solution.

If you're adamant about using PHP to generate the forms, then I would skip the Javascript for now and come up with a solution that works with simple HTTP requests, and then look at using a JS framework to make your forms generate "dynamically".

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the other frameworks but I can say this about the Zend Framework. Its Zend_Form class is very powerfull and flexible. It would be very well suited for a project like that but there is a steep learning curve to Zend_Element_Decorators.

With Zend you would store information about your form in a database using Zend_Db and use that to construct a Zend_Form using its addElement() function to create needed elements.

For sure using this is better then rolling up your own form generation. As far as I know there are no interface between Zend_Db and Zend_Form but you could very much write one. Zend is very flexible, you can pretty much do what you want.

Maybe the other frameworks are better for that I would not know.

Comment: Thanks. I have not yet looked at form_element_decorators but it looks promising. Right now i am working in Yii which has decent methods for rendering forms from arrays (of which this could possible be fetched from a database).

Answer (score 1):

Another form builder solution written in php worth checking out is http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/.  I've used this in my web development and would recommend.  It seems to be well-written and has saved me a lot of time getting projects up and running.